# Sculpting on thick areas effects the both sides of the shape

Tags: sculpting, brushes

While sculpting on thick areas like ears the brush is effecting the both sides of the thick shape. I have seen some people was using a setting before using brushes on thick areas like this and i forget about it.

i'm a foreigner soo here comes the classic, sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

In the brush settings, turn on the *Front Faces Only* option:

[image]

Comment: you were really helpfull, a huge thank you =)